# Mkdir typeerror in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, mkdir

I am trying to write a simple script to create a directory in my C drive called Cake using Python. I followed a tutorial and can't figure out why I am getting an error.

```
os.mkdir("C:\\Cake")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    os.mkdir("C:\\Cake")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

There is no Cake folder that already exists and it is on my personal PC so I do have administrative access. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Python lets you shoot yourself in the foot rather easily sometimes. You replaced the `os.mkdir()` function with a string somewhere.

You must've rebound the `os.mkdir` name to a string earlier in your code:

```
os.mkdir = 'some string'
```

or

```
os.mkdir = some_name_referring_to_a_string
```

Find that line and correct it. If you are seeing this in the shell, reload the module with:

```
reload(os)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir = 'Hello world!'
>>> os.mkdir('/tmp/test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> reload(os)
<module 'os' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> os.mkdir('/tmp/test')
```

Comment: Hmm, how bout that. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: So let me get this straight, he re-assigned `os.mkdir` to a string, and _then_ called it?

Answer (score 0):

after importing os,
you must have set os.mkdir to a string, which is shortened to str in the error.
To fix, reload the os module.
As an example,
    import os
    os.mkdir "stringing along playfully"
    reload(os)
    os.mkdir(r"C:\Cake")